# How can I prevent Qt Creator 2.4.1 from replacing tabs with spaces?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

How can I prevent Qt Creator 2.4.1 from replacing tabs with spaces?

I have chosen ‘Tabs only’ on ‘Tab policy’ but Qt Creator still has this annoying behaviour

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In settings, go to `C++`, and on the `Code Style` tab, press the `Edit` button.
In the new window, you will have a `General Tab` which allows for C++-specific code indentation settings.

Set `Tab policy` to `Tabs only` and `Align continuation lines` (if 2.4.1 already had that, not sure) to  `With Regular Indent` and you should be good.

Note: The same can be done for `Qt Quick`.

Comment: I found the solution “Tabs Only” in Tools -> Options -> C++ -> Code Styles -> Edit

Answer (score 2):

3 years later the issue is still there but ...
in QT5.9.1 - qt-creator go to Tools - Options - Fakevim and click on the button "set Qt Style" and the problem is gone (at least for Makefile(s))